# SFDX exporting then upserting user records

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm trying to use SFDX to export users, add a MobilePone, then upsert them back in.

I used the following to get a .json file of user records:

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -q "SELECT Id, Username, Email, Phone, MobilePhone FROM User" -d ./path/to/my/path -u <username_here>
```

This creates a User.json in my path. I then try to upsert by using the following:

```
sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s User -f ./path/to/my/path/User.json -i Id -w 2 -u <usernamehere>
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid Opening Quote: a quote is found inside a field at line 2
```

I think because the -f is expecting a .csv file, though I could be wrong.

Any better way of approaching this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this with sfdx and not with the REST API directly?

Comment: Easier to do when it's a 1-off and I can use my own computer as credentials rather than a bearer token

Comment: for a 1 off i would look into using the salesforce dataloader then where you get a csv that you can edit in excel or other tools and then upload again through the dataloader

Answer (score 1):

`sf` or `sfdx` does not support upsert using json format yet.
We can follow below approach [I have used sf instead of sfdx but both should work]:

1.Export data in CSV format using below command & `bulk` option :

```
sf data query -q "SELECT Id, Username, Email, Phone, MobilePhone FROM User" --resultformat csv --bulk --wait 0
```

Equivalent sfdx command :

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id, Username, Email, Phone, MobilePhone FROM User" --resultformat csv --bulk --wait 0
```

2.Fetch the result using resume command, job id from 1st step & export to a file:

```
sf data query resume -I <job-id-from-first-step> --target-org <org-alias> > ./csvFile.csv
```

3.Upsert data using sf command[There are some issues in CSV w.r.t. file format]:

```
sf data upsert bulk -s User -f csvFile.csv -i ID -w 2
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667592/salesforce-bulk-api-invalidbatch-field-name-not-found) link incase you get `invalid field` error for step 3

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason to preference csv format over JSON?

Comment: I think CSV is preferred because it consumes less bandwidth , easy to read & faster to process compared to JSON. Do consider marking it as the answer and upvoting if this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work as expected with sfdx. You didn't add an SFDX command that exports.

Comment: It's there in the answer, step 1 & 2 is about export... sf & sfdx are equivalent.